# C# Unsafe code translation?

Tags: c#, silverlight, pointers, unsafe

I have some code that I'm using in a standard C# application.

I'm sharing the library in a Silverlight project that doesn't allow unsafe code.  I don't know much at all about unsafe/pointer logic/arithmetic and was wondering if someone could translate the following code snippet so that it will run without /unsafe.  I don't care about the performance drop since the code won't be called often on the client.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
    public static unsafe int GeStableHash(string name)
    {
        fixed (char* str = name)
        {
            char* chPtr = str;
            int num = 352654597;
            int num2 = num;
            int* numPtr = (int*)chPtr;
            for (int i = name.Length; i > 0; i -= 4)
            {
                num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 27)) ^ numPtr[0];
                if (i <= 2)
                {
                    break;
                }
                num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 27)) ^ numPtr[1];
                numPtr += 2;
            }
            return (num + (num2 * 1566083941));
        }
    }
```

As per reply below, I looked into the Silverlight implementation of this function.

Now I'm even more confused. The code I see in the SL mscorlib.dll string.GetHashCode function looks like this (it uses the unsafe keyword and gives syntax errors in Visual Studio!):

```
[SecuritySafeCritical, ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
public unsafe override int GetHashCode()
{
    IntPtr arg_0F_0;
    IntPtr expr_06 = arg_0F_0 = this;
    if (expr_06 != 0)
    {
        arg_0F_0 = (IntPtr)((int)expr_06 + RuntimeHelpers.OffsetToStringData);
    }
    char* ptr = arg_0F_0;
    int num = 352654597;
    int num2 = num;
    int* ptr2 = (int*)ptr;
    int i;
    for (i = this.Length; i > 2; i -= 4)
    {
        num = ((num << 5) + num + (num >> 27) ^ *ptr2);
        num2 = ((num2 << 5) + num2 + (num2 >> 27) ^ ptr2[(IntPtr)4 / 4]);
        ptr2 += (IntPtr)8 / 4;
    }
    if (i > 0)
    {
        num = ((num << 5) + num + (num >> 27) ^ *ptr2);
    }
    return num + num2 * 1566083941;
}
```

The solution can be found here: 
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7661/c-unsafe-code-translation

Comment: This question might be a better fit for Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is the implementation of [GetHashCode](http://www.dotnetperls.com/gethashcode)

So perhaps you don't need to do anything "datatohash".GetHashCode(); will suffice

Comment: Isn't there some warning that GethashCode can't be relied upon to have the same implementation across various systems?  I figured if I explicitly define the method then I can be sure the implementation is consistent.  Am I understanding that incorrectly?

Comment: Not sure where you heard/saw that, a reference would be good.

Comment: "the .NET Framework does not guarantee the default implementation of the GetHashCode method, and the value it returns will be the same between different versions of the .NET Framework. " http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx

Comment: Are you passing the hashcode between silverlight and say a .net application? If so have you used ILSpy/reflector to look at the implementation on those runtimes?

Comment: No, I haven't used those before.  I'll google it and see what I can come up with.  Thanks!

Comment: ANd yes, I'm passing them betwen a 64 bit .net server and a Silverlight client.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.  :-/  The code revealed via ILSpy has syntax errors and uses the unsafe keyword.  Bizarre!

Comment: don't forget not all .net is easily translatable into C# and ILSpy may not cope. However .net4 and silver light implementations are different but may be functionally the same. Now we know what you are using it for use a hash method such as [sha1managed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1managed(v=vs.95).aspx)  which is supported in silver light and would give a consistent value across platforms. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

The hash code implementations you posted use pointer arithmetic for better performance.  It compiles in Visual Studio if you put it in a .NET Framework project with the "allow unsafe code" option.

It would be possible to compute the same result by using the same logic, but indexing the string directly.  For example, the expression `"Hello, World"[7]` evaluates to `'W'`.

I'll leave the translation itself as the proverbial exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like an [MD5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5.aspx) hash? It's stable, and is implemented in various places.